# C# JSON After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered

Tags: c#, json, parsing

i'm reading Json from a web api, with `Newtonsoft.Json`

most of their page are fine.

But some of them may contain some special character which fail my parsing.

Code is like:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String strJson = client.DownloadString(url);

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(strJson );
```

then i try to convert to UTF8 it still no work:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
String strJson = client.DownloadString(url);
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strJson);
string safeJsonStr= Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(safeJsonStr);
```

please help!

thanks

Comment: I noticed that this type of error is usually associated with an additional '}' at the end of the string.  I made a hack workaround where I caught the exception, tried to parse it again with the last non-white space character removed from the string.

Comment: Good plan David!  I will just go check the error report and go see which character break my program then delete it. if i get more in the future, i will just code to read exceptions and delete the character automatically.

Comment: When you say special character what character did you get? Have you checked whether the source JSON is actually valid? Sometimes it's just BOM at head you can manually skip. Btw you should determine encoding type by response header.

Answer (score 2):

well, finally i find a way.

i see there are some special language, and i feel i need a decode or encode.

then finally i find this works:

```
            client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            strJson = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Comment: Hey Benny. My clients seem to have the same issue. I can't reproduce it but some of the, receive the exact same error. Can you help me reproduce it? What characters cause this? Thanks.